# basic authentication from android app to domino server

Tags: java, android, rest, lotus-domino

I am developing an android app which uses REST api to talk to Domino server. I used basic authentication for the first call (login) and for subsequent calls I used the DomAuthSessID, which I pulled from response header after successful login.

However, at the server level when I look into "Internet Users" section in Domino Administrator UI, I find that each REST call from app to server increases my user count by 1. This means that even though I am sending DomAuthSessID for subsequent REST calls, server creates a new session for me each time app sends a GET/POST/PUT request.

I would like to achieve a functionality that server treats each call (after successful login) as one session. Any ideas on how can I do that ?

Please note that Domino Server is already configured for basic authentication in this case.

Moreover, server has a sessionScope which checks if this is an existing session. If not then it reinitializes all the configuration list for a particular REST call. However, in case request is coming from my app, server has a new sessionScope for each REST call, resulting into a reinitialization for all configuration parameters at server level. This is not desirable as it makes things slow.

I suspect both problems are related OR may be not ? Please help me if someone has some leads here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the domino server remember a "session", you need to configure it accordingly. Change the authentication of your server from "Basic" to "Sessionbased". This is done in the server document. You will also get a "DomAuthSessID"- Cookie, but this time it will be persistant.

After that you will have a "real" session, that you can reuse within its validity (30 minutes by default, can be increased).

If you configure the server to use an LTPAToken (Multple Server (SSO)), then you need to use the Cookies LTPAToken and/or LTPAToken2 (depending on config) instead of the DomAuthSessID.